# jQuery UI Accordion - How to change the element to use for the content panel

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

The markup for the jQuery UI Accordion looks like this...

```
<div id="accordion">

    <h3><a href="#">First header</a></h3>
    <div>First content</div>

    <h3><a href="#">Second header</a></h3>
    <div>Second content</div>

</div>
```

Long story short, the markup for the menu I'm working with is mostly outside of my control.  It looks like this...

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <ul>
        <li class="drop">
            <a href="#">xxxxxxxxxx</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li>xxxxxxxxxx</li>
                <li>xxxxxxxxxx</li>
                <li>xxxxxxxxxx</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">xxxxxxxxxx</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">xxxxxxxxxx</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">xxxxxxxxxx</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I can selectively add a class to the first level list items, which I do if they have a sub menu.  I added "drop" (as shown above) and setup the accordion like this...

```
$("#sidebar").accordion({
    header: 'li.drop'
});
```

That part works fine.  I can see the the jQuery is adding all the accordion classes as its supposed to.  The problem is that the script is looking for a div immediately following the header to use as the content panel.  I cannot wrap `ul class="sub-menu"` in a div because I don't have control of that part of the markup.  I am trying to figure out how to set which element should be used as the content panel, namely the ul with the class "sub-menu".  Any ideas?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordion doesn't look for `div`. It looks for next element after header.
So, you can post-process given markup. Just insert this code before applying accordion:

```
$("li.drop").each(function() {
    $(this).after($(this).find(".sub-menu"));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  Unfortunately it did not solve the problem.  It did move the ul.sub-menu outside of li.drop (the handler), so it is now the next element after the handler.  Using Chrome inspect I can see that ul.sub-menu does have ui-accordion-content and all the other classes in place, but clicking the handler doesn't work.  The display:none; is never applied to ul.sub-menu and the ui-icon on the handler doesn't change either.

Comment: It is strange, because it works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/84JC6/   Maybe it's something in css, that obstructs default behaviour?

Comment: I figured it out.  It was an conflicting JS issue.  I didn't even actually need your code, I just needed you to point out that jQuery UI Accordion "looks for next element after header", not necessarily a div, so you win :)